# How to store CFBitVector (or any CFType) in Core Data using CFData/NSData?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-foundation, cfdata, cfbitvector

I have limited experience working with the Core Foundation types & collections, so apologies if this is obvious.

I'm using the CFBitVector type to store some bit sequences, and I need to store it in a binary data format (so that it can be added to a Core Data store). The most sensible thing seems to be to store this in a `CFData` type, which can be toll-free bridged with an `NSData` and added to the store, but I am unsure of how to do this.

Can anybody help me out with a simple example of storing CFTypes in CF/NSData?

---

***Edit:***

Is this even the right approach? Should I try converting the CFBitVector into a series of `int`s which can then be stored in the data model? Or perhaps a transformable attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I ended up doing this was to roll my own attribute transformer in order to convert a `CFBitVectorRef` into an `NSData` instance. The benefit of this is that I can really cram the bit array tightly into a block of binary data, as in my case I really need to keep the storage size to a minimum.

Below is the implementation of my `CFBitVectorTransformer` class. It essentially reads each bit and packs them into `unsigned char`s ("segments" in the code below), which are then appended to a mutable `NSData` buffer. The code would work with types larger than `unsigned char`s, however I wanted the smallest chunks possible in order to really minimise the size of the resulting data.

```
#define kBitsPerByte    8


@implementation CFBitVectorTransformer


+ (Class)transformedValueClass
{
    return [NSData class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return YES;
}

/* CFBitVectorRef -> NSData */
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    if (!value) return nil;
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) return value;

    /* Prepare the bit vector. */
    CFBitVectorRef bitVector = (__bridge CFBitVectorRef)value;
    CFIndex bitVectorCount = CFBitVectorGetCount(bitVector);

    /* Prepare the data buffer. */
    NSMutableData *bitData = [NSMutableData data];
    unsigned char bitVectorSegment = 0;
    NSUInteger bytesPerSegment = sizeof(char);
    NSUInteger bitsPerSegment = bytesPerSegment * kBitsPerByte;

    for (CFIndex bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < bitVectorCount; bitIndex++) {
        /* Shift the bit into the segment the appropriate number of places. */
        CFBit bit = CFBitVectorGetBitAtIndex(bitVector, bitIndex);
        int segmentShift = bitIndex % bitsPerSegment;
        bitVectorSegment |= bit << segmentShift;

        /* If this is the last bit we can squeeze into the segment, or it's the final bit, append the segment to the data buffer. */
        if (segmentShift == bitsPerSegment - 1 || bitIndex == bitVectorCount - 1) {
            [bitData appendBytes:&bitVectorSegment length:bytesPerSegment];
            bitVectorSegment = 0;
        }
    }

    return [NSData dataWithData:bitData];
}

/* NSData -> CFBitVectorRef */
- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
    if (!value) return NULL;
    if (![value isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) return NULL;

    /* Prepare the data buffer. */
    NSData *bitData = (NSData *)value;
    char *bitVectorSegments = (char *)[bitData bytes];
    NSUInteger bitDataLength = [bitData length];

    /* Prepare the bit vector. */
    CFIndex bitVectorCapacity = bitDataLength * kBitsPerByte;
    CFMutableBitVectorRef bitVector = CFBitVectorCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, bitVectorCapacity);
    CFBitVectorSetCount(bitVector, bitVectorCapacity);

    for (NSUInteger byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < bitDataLength; byteIndex++) {
        unsigned char bitVectorSegment = bitVectorSegments[byteIndex];

        /* Store each bit of this byte in the bit vector. */
        for (NSUInteger bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < kBitsPerByte; bitIndex++) {
            CFBit bit = bitVectorSegment & 1 << bitIndex;
            CFIndex bitVectorBitIndex = (byteIndex * kBitsPerByte) + bitIndex;
            CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex(bitVector, bitVectorBitIndex, bit);
        }
    }

    return (__bridge_transfer id)bitVector;
}


@end
```

This nicely abstracts the conversion of data, allowing you to just set the `CFBitVectorRef` as an attribute in the data model, and should be plenty fast enough for most purposes.

I hope this helps somebody else in a similar situation.

Comment: I came across a problem, that in `- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value`, when *bit* should have been 1, it appears to take value such at 2,4,64,128, etc. So I need to manually do `CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex(bitVector, bitVectorBitIndex, bit!=0)`. Not sure if it's a bug or I didn't use the codes correctly.