# CFBitVector stored as an attribute to a coredata object

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, cfbitvector

I am attempting to create a fingerprint for an object in coreData, and want to set it as attribute to an object. I figured CFBitArray is the way to go.

I am trying to figure out how to save this per object:

Here is an example

Object

attributes:
Name:
Fingerprint ("01010101010101010101010110") etc...

This is used to try to match with a master print

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store CFBitVector (or any CFType) in Core Data using CFData/NSData?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384790/how-to-store-cfbitvector-or-any-cftype-in-core-data-using-cfdata-nsdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to convert that to/from something Core Data understands, and save the converted value. There are a couple of possibilities, both of which involve getting the actual bits via `CFBitVectorGetBits`. Once you have that, you can

- Save them in an `NSData` using something like `+dataWithBytes:length:`, and put that in a binary-type attribute on a managed object. Or...
- Depending on the number of bytes you're using, save them in an `NSNumber` using something like `+numberWithLong:` (or whatever is long enough for the number of bits). Then put that in one of Core Data's integer types-- again, choosing whatever size fits your bits.

You can make the conversion either by using custom accessor methods on your `NSManagedObject` subclass, or by using the *transformable* Core Data attribute type and a value transformer class. For the latter you'd subclass `NSValueTransformer` and implement your conversions there (Apple provides a couple of examples of this).

Depending on what you're actually doing, you might want to consider using `NSIndexSet` instead of `CFBitVectorRef`. If nothing else, it conforms to `NSCoding`-- which means you can use a transformable attribute but rely on Core Data's default value transformer instead of writing your own.

You might also find it a lot simpler to just use one of the integer types and rely on bitwise operators to determine if a bit is set. Then you don't need to do anything special with Core Data, you just choose the appropriately-sized integer type.

Comment: Sounds doable. Ill take your nsindexset suggestions but I think it will be too long for an int (the finger print is a combination of 1500 1s and 0s) this should minimize core data work.

Comment: Yeah, 1500 bits is kind of a lot for a numeric type. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just storing `NSData`? It is way, way easier to store binary data inside `NSData` than inside `CFBitvectorRef`.

If you're trying to store a *hash* / *fingerprint* of something, I assume you're creating a **SHA-256** hash with `CC_SHA256_Init`, `_Update` and `_Final`. Those will give you a so-called digest which is a fingerprint of the data you pass into the `CC_SHA256_Update`.

```c
// Create the context:
CC_SHA256_CTX shaContext;
CC_SHA256_Init(&shaContext);
// For each value:
CC_SHA256_Update(&shaContext, &v, sizeof(v));
// Get the fingerprint / digest:
unsigned char digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA256_Final(digest, &shaContext);
NSData *fingerprint = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:sizeof(digest)];
```

Then you can store that *fingerprint* into a Core Data attribute that's *Binary Data*.

Depending on the type of `v`, you might have to change the call to `CC_SHA256_Update()`. If you do this on an NSObject, you need to call it for each instance variable that you're interested in (that should be part of the fingerprint), e.g. if you have

```c
@property (nonatomic) int32_t count;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
```

you'd do

```c
int32_t v = self.count
CC_SHA256_Update(&shaContext, &v, sizeof(v));

NSData *d = [self.name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Stringencoding];
CC_SHA256_Update(&shaContext, [data bytes], [data length]);
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?